# Удаление определенной метки на яндекс карте

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, yandexmapkit

Я разрабатываю приложение на основе яндекс карт. Столкнулся с 2 серьезными проблемами.

Первая, я прохожусь по сету из точек и добавляю метки на карту. В  зависимости от расстояния метки рисуются по разному. Я прекрасно знаю как удалить все метки, но как удалить только одну, или хотя бы изменить ее рисунок

```
let mapObjects = mapView.mapWindow.map.mapObjects

    for obj in setObject{//сет с кординатами точек

        let placemark = mapObjects.addPlacemark(with: obj)

        placemark.opacity = 0.5
        placemark.isDraggable = true

        if distance <= 1000{
            placemark.setIconWith(image1)
        }else{
            placemark.setIconWith(image2)
        }

    }
```

в документации есть метод

```
- (void)removeWithMapObject:(nonnull YMKMapObject *)mapObject;
```

но как в него передать именно нужную метку

Вторая проблема, заключается в том как сделать метку кликабельной?

Заранее благодарен за любую помощь!

Answer (score 1):

Функция для обработки нажатия:

```
func onMapObjectTap(with mapObject: YMKMapObject, point: YMKPoint) -> Bool
```

Метод для удаления метки:

```
self.mapView.mapWindow.map.mapObjects.remove(with: mapObject)
```

При этом ViewController должен реализовывать: `YMKMapObjectTapListener` и для самой метки нужно установить: `mapObject.addTapListener(with: self)`.